# What does "name::name" means in C++?

Tags: c++

I would like someone to explain me the "name::name" syntax and how it is used on C++ programming. I have been looking through but I don't get it yet. Thanks for help.

Here is context code:

```
void UsbProSender::SendMessageHeader(byte label, int size) const {
    Serial.write(0x7E);
    Serial.write(label);
    Serial.write(size);
    Serial.write(size >> 8);
}
```

Comment: Without any context it sounds like a constructor... but if you want a useful answer I suggest you add more context to your question.

Comment: I just edited the answer and added code

Comment: @FatalError: a constructor would necessarily have the function name at right (here SendMessageHeader) be the same as the class name at left (here UsbProSender), so it can't be a constructor in this case.  It's clearly a member function though - only member functions can be `const`.

Comment: @TonyDelroy Sure. OP Updated the question.  The original had no snippet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`::` is the scope resolution operator.

`std::cout` is the name `cout` in the namespace `std`.

`std::vector::push_back` is the push_back method of std::vector.

In your code example:

```
void UsbProSender::SendMessageHeader(byte label, int size) const {
    Serial.write(0x7E);
    Serial.write(label);
    Serial.write(size);
    Serial.write(size >> 8);
}
```

`UsbProSender::SendMessageHeader` is providing the definition for the `SendMessageHeader` method of the `UsbProSender` class.

Another (more complete) example:

```
class Bar {
    int foo(int i); // forward declaration
};

// the definition
int Bar::foo(int i) {
    return i;
}
```

Comment: thanks for giving the name of the operator that helps me a lot as the syntax examples

Comment: Good answer.  UsbProSender could either be a class or a namespace, right?  You can't tell from the example he gave.

Comment: The function is const, so it must be a member.

Answer (score 2):

It is operator for scope resolution.
Consider that code

```
class A { public: void f(){} };
class B { public: void f(){} };
class C : public A, public B {};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    C c;
    //   c.f(); //  ambiguous: which one of two f() is called?
    c.A::f(); // OK
    c.B::f(); // OK
    return 0;
}
```